Report from Salesforce dashboard widgets (report of reports)
I have several dashboards in salesforce lightning of reports: 58 reports across 5 dashboards. Each widget provides me with a "metric chart" number. However, I need to summarise all of those reports regularly and currently I have to manually do this by viewing and typing in a spreadsheet.
Is there any way I can report on the metric chart numbers across several dashboards of reports?  Like a report of reports?
I wanted to create a report that picks up the data from "metric chart" number widgets. Each report has various filters so I cannot combine all the reports together in one.  The metric of each report should then be able to be reported on.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
